# Any Java counterpart of wget in shell script

Tags: java, url, html, wget

Is there any Java lib that allows me to download web pages recursively given a url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jSpider may fit your needs

http://j-spider.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wget-java](http://code.google.com/p/wget-java/) by Google.